# SDL2 window is transparent

Tags: c++, sdl-2

The SDL window that I created has problem : I can create a window but it's absolutely transparent , you can see through it ( not a white screen and i have no error ) .

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *window = nullptr;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
        std::cout << "SDL Initialization Error : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    else
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (window == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Window creation error :" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            SDL_Delay(2000000);
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do simple rendering you should use the SDL_Renderer API; Specifically `SDL_CreateRenderer`, `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor`, `SDL_RenderClear` and `SDL_RenderPresent`. The `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` stuff is mostly there for porting ancient SDL 1 applications and not really meant for writing new things. In any case, you didn't actually put anything in the window surface (certainly not a white background) so it's not surprising that it doesn't contain anything.

Simple example for using SDL_Renderer:

```
SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
for(bool keep_running = true; keep_running;) {
  for(SDL_Event ev; SDL_PollEvent(&ev);) {
     if(ev.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        keep_running = false;
     }
  }
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
  SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

You can put this right between your `SDL_CreateWindow` and `SDL_DestroyWindow` calls - check out the [SDL2 Wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org) for details on what each of these functions does.